# How to mock ngControl in Custom Form Control - Unit tests Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mocha.js, angular-test

I'm looking for some example with unit tests for Custom Form Control in Angular 9. 
That part `constructor(@Self() private ngControl: NgControl)` causes an error: `Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [NgControl]`. Since I need to set value accessor somehow.

I'm injecting `ngControl` in constructor since I need to use `ngControl` later in my component. That's why I didn't use typical implementation with `provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`.

I was trying to mock it by:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: NgControl, useValue: new FormControlDirective([], [], [], null) }
        ],
        imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
```

But I have an error: `No valid value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute` since I don't know what should be under 3rd parameter of function `FormControlDirective` which is: `valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[]`

Does anyone have idea how can I mock this?

Answer (score 2):

Try mocking it like so:

```
let mockNgControl: any;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockNgControl = jasmine.createSpyObj('ngControl', ['value', /* mock other methods required here */]);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: NgControl, useValue: mockNgControl }
        ],
        imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was because I didn't import my Module with CustomFormControl in Imports array. That's why it didn't work. Maybe it will help someone.